# Is this type of promotion possible in Magento?

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

In 1.5.x, I have spent over two hours trying to figure out the logic to make this promotion work. **I want to sell B for $10 off when you buy A.**

I am using a Shopping Cart Price Rule for $10 off when you place A AND B in the same cart. I tried several different rule combinations, and the closest I've achieved is: 1 of each = $10 off. 2 of each = $20 off and so forth. But when I add 3 A and 2 B (or 3 B and 2 A) to the cart I get $30 off, when it obviously it should be $20.

**How do I make it work so that there is $10 off for each additional PAIR of items?**

Additionally, if possible with NATIVE capacity, I would like the $10 off only work up to the 5th pair. But at this point this is a secondary need.

I have no clue what else to try. Please advise!

Comment: have you check this http://amasty.com/special-promotions-pro.html ?

Comment: I don't think it's possible with native Magento's rules: couldn't you create a bundle of the 2 products and sell it at the price you want?

Comment: I could do that, thanks @OSdave. But I will try individual products first.